# Create object at a certain distance in a specific direction

Tags: python, blender

i want create a plane at a certain distance in a specific direction with respect to the Camera.

more exactly where is the Camera pointing.
This is the basic code, i must find the direction of the camera for add the camera location with my distance and set the location=(x,y,z).

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = scene.camera
rotazione = cam.rotation_euler
location = cam.location

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(
    radius=1.0, 
    view_align=False, 
    enter_editmode=False, 
    location=(x,y,z), 
    rotation=(rotazione.x, rotazione.y, rotazione.z))
```

Any tips?